# Use bipolar transistor to power LED from a certain power on?

Tags: led, bjt

I'm trying to do the following: I have a LED that is supposed to be on, whenever a control voltage (CTRL) exceeds a certain voltage (0.7V). To do this, I created the following circuit:

[image]

I know that a bipolar transistor is controlled by the current, not the voltage and it's probably not the best way to go here. However, it is actually working quite well - except for one thing: When CTRL reaches ~0.6V, the LED is slowly starting to go on until reaching its final brightness at about 0.9V.

Is there any way to make this junction more abrupt - even with an BJT? So the LED does not seem to fade in and out anymore? Maybe I should mention that CTRL itself slowly ranges between 0 and 5V.

Comment: Transistors are amplifiers, not switches; a transistor acting as a switch is in a degenerate mode.

Comment: What you need is a [Schmitt trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger). Why does your CTRL signal slowly ranges between 0 and 5V, where does this come from?

Comment: Maybe a Darlington will solve your problem, although the activation voltage will increase to 1.4V, its gain is much higher (10.000+ vs. 100+ for a generic BJT). The slowly on/off will still be there but the range where that happens will be much smaller.

Comment: *"I know that a bipolar transistor is controlled by the current"* What you believe is false. The Ebers-Moll formulas which provide an accurate model of the BJT relate currents to voltages. Collector current is a function of \$V_{BE}\$. The current ratio model is an approximation that works most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two simple approaches you could take. The first would be to add a second transistor for additional gain, which will make the off-on transition happen over a narrower range of voltages. Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYWyua.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The second approach would be to use the second transistor to create positive feedback for the circuit, causing it to have a "snap action" (hysteresis). However, this would also mean that the on-off transition happens at a lower voltage than the off-on transition. Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnIvDg.png)</sup>

Comment: The first one works pretty good and does look quite simple, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you want to achieve your goal with one BJT + some resistors? Because if not, you could use a simple comparator to make this work.

Comment: Yes, but I'm going to take a look at it, thank you!

Answer (score -4):

you try this circuit and reply
[image]

Comment: Could you explain why this would work?

Comment: I don't think this is functionally any different than what was already in the question.

Comment: capacitor in parallel with base resistor is know as speed-up capacitor. it will force the transistor quickly respond to the input signal(it will reduce the rise time of the signal ).

Comment: @yogece that works because C1 presents a lower impedance than R1 for high frequency signals. In this question, the input is a very slowly changing signal, so C1 presents a high impedance to the input signal (much higher than the 10k of R1) so doesn't measurably affect the circuit operation. Another way to think about it: the current through a capacitor is proportional to the rate of change of voltage. The slowly changing input voltage will mean the current through C1 is always insignificantly small.